# How to split the large text file into records based on the row size in Python or PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a large text file with 15GB of size. The data inside the text file is considered as the single string with some 20million records of data. Each record is of length 5000. Each record is having 450+ column

Now I want to split the each record of the text file into new line. And split the each record as per the schema with some delimiter to load it as a Dataframe.

This is the sample approach - sample data:

```
HiIamRowData1HiIamRowData2HiIamRowData3HiIamRowData4HiIamRowData5HiIamRowData6HiIamRowData7HiIamRowData8
```

Expected output:

```
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#1#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#2#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#3#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#4#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#5#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#6#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#7#
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#8#
```

Code:

```
### Schema 
schemaData = [['col1',0,2],['col2',2,1],['col3',3,2],['col4',5,3],['col5',8,4],['col6',12,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data= schemaData, columns=['FeildName','offset','size'])
print(df.head(5))


file = 'sampleText.txt'
inputFile = open(file, 'r').read()

recordLen = 13
totFileLen = len(inputFile)
finalStr = ''

### First for loop to split the each record based on record length
for i in range(0,totFileLen,recordLen):
    record = inputFile[i:i+recordLen]
    recStr = ''

    ### Second For loop to apply the Schema on top of each record.
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        #print(record[row['offset']:row['offset'] + row['size']])
        recStr = recStr + record[row['offset']:row['offset'] + row['size']] + '#'  
    recStr = recStr + '\n'
    finalStr += recStr
print(finalStr)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(finalStr)
```

> For the above 8 rows sample data It is taking 56 (8 rows + 48 row times column) Total Iterations.
> In real Data set I am having 25 Million Rows and 500 columns. It will take  25 mil + 25 mil X 500col Iterations

Constraints:

1. The entire data in the text file is sequence data, all the records are placed next to each other and entire data is in one string. I want to read the text file and write the final Data to new text file.
2. I don't want to split the File into smaller size chunks while processing. Like 50 MB of data files, by doing this IF the last record got splits between the half first 50MB and second chunk of 50MB, Then from second 50MB chunk onwards the data will be wrong sliced. As we are slicing each record based on the length of record 5000.
3. If I can split the each chunk based on the File length inside the text file that will be possible approach.

I have tried the below python approach. For smaller files it is working fine. But for the file >500MB onwards its taking hours to split the each record schema wise.

I have tried multithreading and multiprocessing approach too didn't seen much improvement there.

**QUESTION**: Is there any better approach for this problem either in Python or PySpark? To reduce the time complexity.

Comment: Are you able to use a Linux shell? Then you could use [fold](https://ss64.com/bash/fold.html) for the first step: `fold -w 13 <your file>` and then continue processing with Spark

Comment: I guess you're not reading the whole 15GB file with `open(file, 'r').read()` in your real code, right?

Comment: hi @werner I have to use either python or Pyspark/Scala. Linux is not option for us.

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest , Yes I am not reading the whole 15GB file. I have mentioned the approach I am Taking on Sample data.

Comment: @Anvesh, do you expect the `#` to be a field separator or it could be any other sign, like `,`?

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest The data contains the most of the characters `(,./:';'[{&.....)` as part of data. So I am planning to give some unique separator like `"#*#*#"`. So that the data frame will load properly on top of final separated data.

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively process your big file iteratively by:

- capturing a sequential chunk of the needed size at a time

  - passing it to [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) with predefined column widths

    - and immediately export the constructed dataframe to the output csv file (creates it if it doesn't exist) appending the line with specified separator

---

```
from io import StringIO

rec_len = 13
widths = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

with open('sampleText.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w+') as out:
    while (line := inp.read(rec_len).strip()):
        pd.read_fwf(StringIO(line), widths=widths, header=None) \
            .to_csv(out, sep='#', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

---

The `output.txt` contents I get:

```
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#1
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#2
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#3
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#4
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#5
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#6
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#7
Hi#I#am#Row#Data#8
```

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for this solution. if I want to give the another separator which length is more than 1 i believe its not possible right .?

Comment: @Anvesh, Both `pd.Dataframe.to_csv` or `csv.writer` require  One-character string used to separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can achieve the same result using PySpark UDF with Spark functions. Let me show you how in 5 steps:

Import necessary

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, split, explode
```

1. Reading text file using Spark read method

```
sample_df = spark.read.text("path/to/file.txt")
```

2. Convert your custom function to PySpark UDF (User Defined Function) inorder to use it in Spark

```
def delimit_records(value):
    recordLen = 13
    totFileLen = len(value)
    finalStr = ''

    for i in range(0,totFileLen,recordLen):
        record = value[i:i+recordLen]

        schemaData = [['col1',0,2],['col2',2,1],['col3',3,2],['col4',5,3],['col5',8,4],['col6',12,1]]
        pdf = pd.DataFrame(data= schemaData, columns=['FeildName','offset','size'])
        
        recStr = ''
        for index, row in pdf.iterrows():
            recStr = recStr + record[row['offset']:row['offset'] + row['size']] + '#'  
        recStr = recStr + '\n'
        finalStr += recStr
        
    return finalStr.rstrip()
```

3. Registering your User Defined Function

```
delimit_records = udf(delimit_records)
```

4. Use your custom function against the column, you want to modify

```
df1 = sample_df.withColumn("value", delimit_records("value"))
```

5. Split the record based on delimiter "\n" using PySpark split()
   function

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("value", split("value", "\n"))
```

6. Use the explode() function to transform a column of arrays or maps
   into multiple rows

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("value", explode("value"))
```

7. Let's print the output

```
df3.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#1#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#2#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#3#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#4#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#5#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#6#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#7#|
|Hi#I#am#Row#Data#8#|
+-------------------+
```